# How to add lines on top of python datashader points canvas?

Tags: python, datashader

I am trying to plot (longitude, latitude points), and on top, illustrate the shortest path from A to B with some lines.

```
  cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=3000, plot_height=3000, x_range=(minLon, maxLon), y_range=(minLat, maxLat))
    cv1 = ds.Canvas(plot_width=3000, plot_height=3000, x_range=(minLon, maxLon), y_range=(minLat, maxLat))
    agg = cvs.points(df, 'x', 'y')  # this is the histogram
    agg1 = cv1.line(positionsOfNodesInShortesPathDF, 'x', 'y', line_width=5)
    
    img = ds.tf.set_background(ds.tf.shade(agg, how="cbrt", cmap=cc.fire), "black").to_pil() # create a rasterized image
    
    path = ds.tf.set_background(ds.tf.shade(agg1, how="log", cmap=cc.fire), "black").to_pil() # create a rasterized image
```

And for now, I am making the background of the path image transparent like so

```
    newImage = []
    for item in path.getdata():
        if item[:3] == (0, 0, 0):
            newImage.append((0, 0, 0, 0))
        else:
            newImage.append(item)

    path.putdata(newImage)
    
    

    im.alpha_composite(img, path).save("combined.png")
```

Which results in this output:[image]

But - this doesn't seem scaleable. My question is therefore, if there is another workaround for this?
What if I to highlight other specific points of my map - e.g. start end end point?

Comment: Can you fix the formatting so the code is clearer and also explain what about this seems hard to scale? It’s hard to tell exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The background of the path image should *already* be transparent; `tf.set_background` is what changes it from transparent to black. So if you skip setting the background, you should be able to composite `path` directly on top of `img`, *then* set the background to black on the final result. Same for any other points you want to overlay.

You can also use `tf.stack(img, path)` to do the compositing.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Do you have any suggestion for what I could do if I want to plot a dot both at the start and the end of the end of the white line? Right now I simply plot the image created by datashader in matplotlib and then convert the coordinates of the start and end, but do you know if there is a smarter way?